# xamarin project type incompatible

Tags: visual-studio, xamarin, xamarin.ios, xamarin.android

This error started showing from yesterday, I remember installing Web development packages and updates windows. Before that if was working fine.

If I reload project same error shows up.

The application which this project type is based on was not found. 
Please try this link for further information: 
http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkID=299083&projecttype=EFBA0AD7-5A72-4C68-AF49-83D382785DCF

This link redirects https://www.xamarin.com/visual-studio page , which is nothing but xamarin download page.

I tried uninstalling Xamarin packages and reinstalling.

It did not solve the issue.

Now I am doing complete uninstall of MS Visual Studio 2017

Please note that no changes have been made to csproj or solution file.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Complete uninstall of Visual Studio** along with C++ distributables from Control Panel > Programs and Features and then **re-installing** Visual Studio fixed the issue. Seems its caused by errors in installation

Microsoft should code properly and let programmers know if there were errors and 'repair' option is supposed to fix them. I don't know why these things are missed out in roll-outs.

Answer (score 11):

I get the "xamarin project type incompatible" frequently. (VS2015)

The solution for me:

1. Close down VS.
2. In the src project folder delete the .vs folder.
3. Restart VS.

Comment: I got it for the first time, "MyProject.Android (incompatible)". I exited VS2019, deleted my .vs folder, and everything was good.